# How do you create a perfect pygame fullscreen?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game, and I want it to be fullscreen. However, the pygame fullscreen is strange, creating a screen too large. So I referred to this: [Pygame FULLSCREEN Display Flag Creates A Game Screen That Is Too Large For The Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274460/pygame-fullscreen-display-flag-creates-a-game-screen-that-is-too-large-for-the-s). However, when I followed these instructions

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
true_res = (ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1))
pygame.display.set_mode(true_res,pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

from an answer (but instead using pywin32 instead of ctypes, like this: `win32api.GetSystemMetric(0)`).
I used this, and while it does create a fullscreen, it also creates a black border around my screen and enlarges everything a slight bit, including my cursor. How can I get rid of this black border and get all shapes to normal size? Or is there a better way to create a good fullscreen? 
If it helps, I use Windows 10.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need a [mcve] to assist you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the resolution of a monitor in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954469/how-to-get-the-resolution-of-a-monitor-in-pygame)

Comment: @LEEE no, it is not the duplicate..

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem of enlarging everything arose with the use of ctypes module as because the ctypes module makes use of a function named as GetSystemMetrics() whose work is to get the size of the screen of your system.

And might be the `import pygame` is loading some `dll` that is not compatible with a `dll` that `windll` needs.

So I suggest either you `update the ctype library or pygame library` or **update both libraries** or you can enlarge screen size by providing custom width and height values according to the resolution supported by your system.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: @Ethanol if my answer doesn't helps then you can tell me. I will dig up more to help you out.. :)